# laravel not creating new table

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have only one new migration file which is 2017_02_05_121119_create_posts_table.php but when I run "php artisan migrate" it says "[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException] Cannot redeclare class CreateUsersTable".

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
    }
}
```

Comment: do one thing, remove migrations table straight away, and again fire that php artisan migrate command, it will work, but do you have data in your tables, which were already migrated, then take a backup of it, then clear your database and then run the command

Comment: I did the same, migration created successfully but the posts table did not create

Comment: post your that script of migration of post in your question, I am sure, there is something wrong with that class name

Comment: ok let me take a look to add code in question

Comment: please have a look on code

Comment: Check your all names of classes, because in this file, there is no issue

Comment: this is new project and I did not make any changes in the project. this is the file only I created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit AppServiceProvider.php and include "use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;" and then in boot method add this line "Schema::defaultStringLength(191);"

Answer (score 1):

Have you made a copy/paste for this migration? looks like you left the classname of a previus one, because the seed is create posts but the class create users.

Comment: I got it thanks @Rocco I have changed class name but an other issue comes... now it says  [PDOException]                                                               
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' alre  
  ady exists

Comment: it is not creating new table

Comment: same thing on the first row of the migration you have to change the name of the table from user to posts

Comment: this file is ok, but when you start a migration, if it ends with an error could happen that it does not set it as don in migration table.so it looks loke it it trying to re create user table that already exists. try todrpmanually the entire db and make migration all over again

Answer (score 0):

In the Providers folder edit the AppServiceProvider.php file.

You just need to add these two lines to it:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
```

and in the boot function:

```
 Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
```

[image]